# How to uninstall compizconfig settings manager from ubuntu 17.04

Tags: compiz

How do I completely uninstall compizconfig settings manager from ubuntu 17.04?
I have used

```
sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager
```

command but I can still see the animations occurring when I run applications.

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get purge compizconfig-settings-manager`

Comment: If you uninstall the manager, it doesn't mean thet it will revert the settings made by it.

Answer (score 0):

Please this more comprehensive tool:

```
sudo apt-get purge compizconfig-settings-manager
```

This will remove and also delete any configuration files

Comment: I did this but it still exists